# Can someone help me with this question about relationships?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

First sorry for my English, i don't speak this language.
So...I have a set A and one relationship R in A, if the affirmation bellow is true,make the demonstration,else show one counterexample.

idA ⊆ R⁻¹ ∪ R.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't true. Take $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$, and $R = \{<1,2>\}$. Then $R \cup R^{-1}$ is $\{<1,2>,<2,1>\}$ which doesn't contain $IdA$.